# What is Bush Mosteller algorithm?

Tags: reference-request

I cannot find anything interesting on the internet. What is the Bush Mosteller stochastic model? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original paper seems to be

> Robert R. Bush and Frederick Mosteller, [A Stochastic Model with Applications to Learning](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177728914), *Ann. Math. Statist.*
>   Volume 24, Number 4 (1953), 559–585.